# Query to get the number of errors reported by PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any internal table recording the number of errors produced by Postgres?

I was expecting something like:

```
select 
    database, count(*) 
from 
    pg_errors 
where 
    type='error' and date > (now() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not tracked inside the database.

You could mine the log file for `ERROR` entries — `log_destination = 'csvlog'` will make it easier.

One option to process `csvlog`s (thanks, a_horse_with_no_name!) is to use them with a [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) foreign table to access them with SQL from PostgreSQL.

Comment: Maybe a good proxy could be `select xact_rollback from pg_stat_database;`?